# 2003 Ford Escape V6 oil light showing

Tags: ford, oil, escape

I have a 2003 Ford Escape V6. Like a couple of months ago my oil light popped on (most of the time only when I hit the brakes). The oil light goes off when I hit the accelerator or on motion. And this light sometimes pop on and stay on while driving.

My oil levels always between min and max. I don't know what is the problem. 
I will be glad for help to know how to go about this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. First of all, Ford says "*If illuminated while engine is running or you’re driving, a malfunction is indicated. Stop your vehicle as soon as it is safe to do so, and switch the engine off. Check the engine oil level. If you find that your engine oil is at the appropriate level, yet the warning lamp remains lit, do not resume driving. Have the system checked by your authorized dealer immediately.*" Has routine maintenance been performed on this engine (when was the last oil change)? How many miles are on the engine? Have you had the codes read?

Comment: I have this same problem happening on my 2002 Ford Escape. Had an oil change, light still kept coming on. Had the oil pressure sensor replaced, light still kept coming on. My mechanic has no idea what's causing this.

Answer (score 1):

The oil light is due to sediments in the crankcase clogging the oil pump pick-up screen & tubing.  I had the same problem a few weeks ago and resolved the matter with a motor oil & filter change.  If it were a more serious problem, the light would not go off so easily when you press the gas pedal.

If the problem only improves somewhat or is still unresolved, substitue 16 oz. of motor oil with Marvel Mystery Oil (do not overfill the crankcase).  Change the oil & filter in two hundred miles, but then substitute 32 oz. of oil with MMO and drive 500 miles before changing the oil & filter again.  Keep using the MMO in the crankcase and changing the oil & filter every additional 1,000 miles, for up to 3,000 miles.

This process will clear any stubborn clogs.  It works best when the engine is hot, so drive the car at highway speeds as much as possible (or drive 35 MPH in L1 gear).  It also helps to use Mobil 1 motor oil, though it is considerably more expensive.

Comment: Engine cleaner was used before the old oil was removed. Then replace new oil and filter changed. The oil light still shows after driven for 20mins When brake is applied. It then goes off when accelerated. Please what next to do?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is replace the oil pressure switch. Worst case scenario is a possible bad oil pump.